# Replacing inline block with floats

Tags: html, css

I have managed to achieve the effect I want but by using display block and display inline block and this can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vvDJ9/9/

```
#header h1, #header ul, #header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I was wondering if it was possible to achieve the same effect without using inlineblocks and blocks and instead just using floats.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm unable to understand the problem you are facing with display: inline-block. By default h1, ul, li are block level elements which cannot be displayed side by side without using display: inline-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can get the same effect by using floats.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vvDJ9/12/)

Add `overflow:auto` to `#header`:

```
#header {
    background-color:#1ABC9C;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Add `list-style-type: none;` to `#header ul`:

```
#header ul {
    font-size: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Add `clear:left` to `#content`

```
#content {
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    padding: 20px;
    clear:left;
}
```

And replace `display:inline-block` with `float:left`:

```
#header h1, #header ul, #header ul li {
    float:left;
}
```